# Is it still possible to restore deleted untracked files in git?

Tags: git, git-reset

let's say yesterday I did some changes on my master branch, and I forgot to add, commit them. and in the morning i did

```
git reset --hard
```

is it possible to restore deleted files in this situation ?

Comment: If you happened to `git add` these files at some point, even if you never committed them, they will still be hanging around as blobs until they're garbage collected (in about two weeks). `git fsck` will list the objects as [dangling or unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36671659/712526). You can then use `git cat-file -p deadbeef > old-file-name` to restore them.

Comment: ([Pod's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45815093/712526) already covers this, whoops!)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25791533/712526

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Some better IDEs keep track of your files as a local history. If you removed files externally (say, `git reset`) you should be able to click in your IDE on parent directory and choose "Compare with local history".

I used this feature successfully in `PHPStorm` IDE when my untracked files got wiped out by some utility...

Comment: For Eclipse, navigate to the folder/package that the file was in (Project Explorer or Package Explorer view), right-click, and select `Restore from Local History...` from the context menu.

Comment: omg... You saved my life. I was using `git reset --hard` in a zero commit project, which means `git fsck --lost-found` not work. Luckily I read your answer and use `revert history` in WebStorm and successfully got the wiped codes...

Comment: But be careful, it doesn't work with excluded directories/files in WebStorm (and other Jetbrains products) - and should not, obviously =)

Comment: @RuslanMakrenko very good point :-) there is only hope that files were not excluded :-)

Comment: Nice, I have to try this if it happens to me again. Up to now I've been using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52298924/1529709) several times, with success.

Comment: Thank you! In PHPStorm 2019.1, right-click folder name, Local History > Show History. Then, select and revert the files to restore.

Comment: @JovanPerovic would you please marry me? thank you!

Comment: LIFESAVER!!!!!!

Answer (score 33):

For VScode, the Below steps worked for me to restore deleted untracked file

1. CTRL + SHIFT + P
2. LOOK FOR: "Local History: Find Entry to Restore"
3. SEARCH FOR DELETED FILE
4. SELECT THE LAST SAVED FILE TO OPEN

Comment: I usually don't say this on the first date, but I love you

Comment: Damn! LIFE SAVER :)

Comment: THANK YOU! This helped my case, lost my untracked files when stashing. With vscode being such a commonplace in many development environment, this should be higher up.

Comment: biggest relief of my life. thanks

Comment: Man.. This is a literal LIFE SAVER!!!

Comment:  Life saver !! May you have a wonderful week 

Answer (score 17):

**In Intellij how to recover the untracked revert changes**

**Step 1:** Select the Folder , Right click on it

**Setp 2:** Go to Local History, and then go to Show history

[image]

**Step 3:** Select the untracked files that your revert accidentally. then select those file in right side panel and revert the changes, you will get the files in reverted format.

[image]

Comment: you're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 7):

`git reset --hard` is a very dangerous command, so be careful when you use it next time :)

If you do not have any commit for those files, it seems you have no chance restore them.

Otherwise, reflog command can help you.

Answer (score 7):

[`git fsck`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck) may be able to help you.

If you have not done garbage collection yet it might be able to help you.
Once you have the blob id you can say:

`git show {blobId}`

Answer (score 6):

`git reset --hard` won't remove untracked files. `git clean` will, however.

However if you `git add` the files, don't `git commit` them and then run `git reset --hard` those files **will** be lost.

But it's ok, as they can be recovered, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25792257/57461). (Well, until the next `git gc`).

Answer (score 6):

(**Note**: *The steps seem to have changed a bit, since the accepted answer was posted. But the idea remains the same.*)

To add to the accepted answer, I was able to recover my deleted files using Webstorm 2016.

1. First, I lost my file doing a forced clean using git `git clean -f`.
2. To recover it, I went in Webstorm and did the following steps:

- Go to Project tab for your project, right click to get to 'Show History' under 'Local History'.

[image]

- Once 'Show History' is clicked, one can see the pop up with 'External Change -> Revert' in it. Click to revert the desired files on right.

[image]

- After the above 2 steps, you should see your file come back in 'Project' tab. 'Local History' pop up will show something like in this attached picture.

Reverted to External Change
[image]

You will get an option to get it add to Git.

- To untrack it, just do a `git reset HEAD <filename>` from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access to previous version of untracked deleted files from git, because, of coruse, they do not exist. I would recover them from some backup (maybe there are hidden backup files left by the ide/editor?), or, in alternative, I  would avoid working on that filesystem too much and start searching for recovery tools.

Comment: Good call on the editor! I had discarded untracked changes from a file by accident (curse the Github app) but realised I still had the file open in Atom and could simply hit "undo" to get my changes back.

Comment: @henrebotha, hi! this just happened with me, but unfortunately I didn't have my atom opened at the point of git hard reset, do you know of any possible way I could be saved. Very foolishly I had tons of things in my untracked files.

Comment: @gdad-s-river You should still be able to open Atom up after the fact and hit `undo`, as long as you edited the file in Atom at some point.

Comment: @henrebotha, the problem is that I had closed the files in the atom before I closed the atom itself so there were no open buffers of files to undo.

Comment: @gdad-s-river Unless Atom changed how it works (or you configured it in a strange way), you should be able to open the files up and hit undo.

Comment: @henrebotha, I don't know about if Atom changed, but I hadn't configured it in a strange way. Do you know a strange atom config way that would enable one to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If file retrieval tools like "recuva" didn't work, do the following:

1. If you have build the solution at least once then there will be DLLs (In .net intermediate language files are called DLLs) stored in your Debug/Release or some other folder.
2. Then try disassembling the DLLs using tools like DotPeek etc.

This worked for me. I was able to retrieve the content.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, go to the folder in which you kept these files > Right click > properties > "Previous revisions" and double click on a recent revision. It'll show how all of these files were at that time mentioned there.
Open the files you want and if it's the one you want copy the contents and paste in your current file.

The `Local History` method or simply clicking `ctrl+z` (undo) in the editor you wrote it in, as mentioned in the other answers is the best answer. But this method came in handy when I didn't actually code in an IDE that supports local history.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Git, you can recover your untracked files using this command: `git add <filename>`

If you want to recover all of the deleted untracked files, you can do so simply with this command: `git add .`