# unstaged files gone after git reset --hard

Tags: git, addition, reset, head, reflog

I tried the `git reset --hard HEAD@{n}` from `git reflog` and I lost everything with my current unstaged files :'(

the unstaged files is the last `git add` I did, before then I tried `git reset` to the last `git commit`.

And all my files gone, I can't go back to the `git add` before last commit :'(

Comment: If you used `git add` that added files to the stage, so they're not "unstaged". But losing unstaged changes - actually any changes to the working tree at all - is [what the `--hard` option does](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2530073/306084).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5473/306084 ?

Comment: @pjmorse, ohh I see, actually I had a few backup files, but a way too old. This is my bad move to not knowing the what `git reset --hard` exactly does :'(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I undo git reset --hard HEAD~1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/how-can-i-undo-git-reset-hard-head1)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's not clear if you lost files in your working directory, or files in
the index.  You say you lost your "unstaged files", but then you mention
you might have run "git add".   "unstaged files" are lost for good.

Staged files can be recovered with

```
git fsck --full --unreachable --no-reflog
```

For each file added there will be a lost blob object, and for each
directory entry there will be a tree object.  You would recover your
file changes by doing

```
git cat-file -p SHA
```

For each file that you had modified

`(master)$ vi bar
(master)$ vi baz
(master)$ vi foo
(master)$ git add foo bar baz
(master)$ git reset --hard HEAD
HEAD is now at ead8fa2 initial
(master)$ git fsck --full --unreachable --no-reflog
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
unreachable blob 0c29287001b29159f11c4e8a320bce7e9789c00b
unreachable blob 1524d3478e3d0b92866a53239b10bcd4b3838c4d
unreachable blob 97b724e770249816c61d8a526415986208ed7e15
// take a look at one of the objects
(master)git cat-file -p 0c29287001b29159f11c4e8a320bce7e9789c00b
changes for bar
//Here, based on inspecting the output, I can determine that 0c29287 was the file "bar"
(master) git cat-file -p 0c29287 > bar`

(note I didn't get any lost trees when I tested, so this part may not work)

If you modified a whole bunch of files it is probably easier to recover
via the tree object instead of individual files

```
git read-tree SHA
```

Where SHA is the lost tree object for the root tree.

Comment: thank you for showed me these commands :) but, should I `cd` first to the **its source directory** before I `git cat-file -p SHA`?

Comment: The output of cat-file is just the file contents.  You will need to inspect the contents and determine which file it corresponds to.  Then you would overwrite the appropriate file with the new contents.  The command itself can be run from anywhere.  I'll edit the answer

Comment: yeah I lost my "unstaged files" on **develop** branch but also it affects the files on my **master** branch :'( #they are gone as well. The "unstaged files" is the one I modified from **develop**, I did nothing on **master** after `git reset --hard` the files gone as well T__T

Comment: Thank you very much sir :) finally, I found another my **modified** files before `git reset --hard`, even it's just 3 of them I could recover, the rest of it didn't show from `git fsck --full --unreachable --no-reflog`.

Comment: Thanks a million sir :) you saved me from a big trouble.

Answer (score 11):

All unstaged/uncommited files will be deleted with git reset **--hard**

Using --hard is not recomended since that option **removes** ALL unstaged/uncommited files, instead you should **stash** first and then use normal reset

Instead of

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{n}
```

You should do

```
git stash
git reset HEAD@{n}
```

Your code is then saved in the stash stack, you can retrieve it again by doing

```
git stash pop
```

Although this command merge the "stashed" changes with their current HEAD (an stash is implemented like a branch) is recommended to do stash retrievals on the same commits where these stashes was generated

Comment: +1 for recommending `stash`. But I wouldn't say `--hard` is "not recommended" - sometimes you *want* to clobber the entire working tree.

Comment: "Never use --hard", that was words of **Scott Chacon**, and in my personal experience each time someone use "--hard" it gets to "Oh crap, I need my code again :("

Comment: If my reputation was higher I would downvote this.  Git reset --mixed is not equivalent to git reset --hard, and 'git reset --hard' has all kinds of uses, even though it is potentially dangerous.

Comment: Maybe the --hard option is matter of preferences Just in case, I think this would help: http://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html, 
--hard is the only reset mode can't be undone. IMHO, the effectiveness of Git is making quick things because we know it can easily be undone, I am not used to use 'git reset --hard' because I dont like spending too much time thinking about the code I will remove and I can never get back. But again, is matter of tastes

Another useful link: http://vimeo.com/32608318 (sorry, in spanish)

Comment: reset --HARD is not working directory safe.  Neither is 'rm'.  They are both 'useful'.  If you actually do the reset as you suggest and reset HEAD@{n} it is going to unstage all the changes that were added between HEAD@{n} and HEAD, and they will all show up in the 'git status' output. Which also has its uses, but probably not in this instance.

Comment: On my suggested command sequence, git reset HEAD@{n} is not going to unstage anything, since we do git stash before that

Comment: @dseminara yeah, awfully I didn't think twice to use git reset **--hard** :'( But, I didn't know either if the `git reset --hard` did delete all the files on another **branches** too T__T

Comment: whenever I tried to copy from my backed up folder, I can't do `checkout` because it's told me that I should **remove/moe** the files or it will be overwritten >_<

Comment: this the scenario:
1. I lost my files on **develop** branch  
2. I `git checkout master`, and the files are gone T__T  
3. Still on **master**, I copied the files from **backup** dir, I pasted the files to dir that were gone before **reset --hard** :'(  
4. Everytime I try to `git checkout develop` it tells me:  

`$ git checkout develop  
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:  
   some files/folder  
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.  
Aborting`

Answer (score 10):

If anyone made the same blunder like me `git reset --hard` before adding unstaged files then there are still chances to get those changes back. Although these files are not available in repo anymore but some of the new IDEs maintain their own history. Like in my case I was able to retrieve my unstaged changes from **Android Studio's** local history feature which is located under VCS.

**Directions:**

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

Answer (score 5):

Low tech tip which might be useful for some. If the unstaged/uncommited files that you lost, where open in your editor. Try doing undo on that file and you should get "previous versions" of the file from the editors history stack.

Comment: I'd call this a smart tip.

Answer (score 3):

*Similar to the answers from UsamaAmjad and Juank.*

If you used a nice enough IDE/Editor:

- Hit Ctrl+Z on each file you had modified,
- If you are lucky (like I was) you will presented with a pop up, "Undo reload from disk"
- Hit "yes".

Notes:

- This worked for my unstaged files
- I did this in PyCharm, so it will probably work in other JetBrains/Idea-based IDEs
- At the time of git reset, the IDE probably needed to be open
- At the time of git reset, the files probably needed to be open in an editor window

Comment: To add to the notes, I had a file open in VS Code that had its changes obliterated by `git reset --hard`, and using undo retrieved the unstaged. changes in my case as well.

Answer (score 3):

if anyone searching for a solution using Pycharm IDE,

- find folder for deleted file,
- with right click select , "Show History",
- In left panel you will see history of changes in that folder.

Then find file you deleted, right click to it and select "revert", then deleted files will appear in folder.

Comment: Saved my life. Restored unstaged files too.

Answer (score 1):

If you have staged the files with `git add`, it can still be found back. But if the files are not staged, I have to say there's no way. :(

Just remember that `git reset` is really not safe, especially for the unstaged files.

But if the files are really really important, what I can think of is that you may stop modifying any data in your disk, and try disk recovery with the tools such as `finaldata`. It might find something back if lucky, because you have already overwritten some files after `git reset`.

Anyway, `Git` is really a powerful and cool tool if you are familiar with it.

Comment: yeah, I do lack of git knowledge :'( I still have a few option before using like **finaldata** services, I have old backup files though, even it's way too old >_<, now I understand the **high risk** to consider first before using `git reset` :) Thank you very much sir!

Comment: NP. Backing up files are always useful and robust though not fancy. Sometimes I just do backup if i'm not sure what to do. :)

Comment: Yeah, agreed with you! Me as well :D backup, backup always remember to backup unless we encounter less storage T__T

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar idea to all the above, but in my case, I had written `git status` before and had a list of all the changed files in my terminal, where I could copy the list of files from, then open the files one-by-one on Visual Code (and hope it still had file-changes cached). Check if you have the file-list somewhere and hope your editor has cached copies saved.

Answer (score 0):

One more "If you're using a specific IDE..." answer...

If you're using IntelliJ (or I suspect any other JetBrains IDEs) then you can:

- Right click on the folder that the file(s) were in
- Select "Local History -> Show History"
- Browse down on the "External change" items until you find the one that shows all your deleted files.

  - It looks like the 'reset --hard' shows up as multiple file deletes to IntelliJ, so there may be multiple 'External change' in the list. Go down to the last one with the timestamp around when you did the rest
- Right click the 'External change' and click "Revert"

More details:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/02/local-history-in-intellij-idea-may-save-your-life-code/