# git: why is operations in master branch affect my private branches

Tags: git

I have two branches below:

```
 $ git branch
      master
    * mvn
```

`mvn` branch had a modified file 
when i did `git checkout master` and then `git reset --hard HEAD^` it also did the same op for the mvn branch, meaning my modified file was gone .

what can i do so that the ops in master branch do not affect `mvn` branch or vice versa?

Comment: Did you commit your changes to `mvn` before switching to `master`?

Comment: @0x5453 they are left as modified

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25791647/2550406)

Comment: What do you mean by "mvn branch had a modified file"?  Do you mean that you had a file that was modified in the working directory and the mvn branch was checked out?  Then, when you checked out 'master', you had a modified file in the working directory.  Then you did reset --hard and you no longer had a modified file in the working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible things can be done

1. Whenever someone needs to go another branch, he/she should commit the current changes. If this is not the in commit stage yet then a dummy commit can also be an option.Later dummy commit can be updated in a meaningfull one through `git ammed`.
2. If one don't want to keep the changes or wants to put this changes in another branch then he/she should stash the current changes and pop the stash in targeted branch.

Comment: oh so branches are commits only? if if it has changes not committed then chaning branches will not be isolated to that branch?