# How can I undo that unstaged changes were deleted by git reset --hard HEAD^?

Tags: git, version-control, recovery, git-reset

I was working on my project, and I made a wrong commit (the last commit) and wanted to permanently delete it from the git logs, and I did the following command:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

The problem is that I didn't make add on my changes, so all changes which are unstaged were deleted.

Now, how do I get all the changes back?

Comment: @jonrsharpe no, I tried but to no avail, it seems that they has staged their changes .

Comment: Also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/25791533/3001761 - there are plenty of git-related posts here already, not to mention resources like https://ohshitgit.com/.

Comment: Will this post not work : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/how-can-i-undo-git-reset-hard-head1

Answer (score 2):

As the git documentation specifies:

> git reset
> --hard Resets the index and working
> tree. Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since 
> are discarded.

If there is no restore source (stash, add, commit) I know of no way to restore your files since git doesn't 'auto-updates' a current snapshot of your working tree