# Load file back from local history in Brackets IDE

Tags: adobe-brackets

We use Adobe Brackets on Windows OS. Is there any way to get file back from its local history in Brackets IDE?
You know, many of ides save file`s local history without need for a vcs.

Answer (score 2):

There’s no such thing as a local history in Adobe Brackets at the time of writing. But you can upvote the corresponding [backlog item](https://trello.com/c/H8AyDwFA/391-local-history-versioning) to increase its priority.

Comment: Nice to have that feature as I want to [recover the discarded unstagged/uncommited changes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9750049/1179841) from `git reset --hard`

Answer (score 0):

You are going to load a past history of the file from a Windows Backup. Before you do it you need to anticipate that that backup is not going to contain any current additions. So to save some time you need to (for example) copy and paste the full extent of your current css file into notepad, and also copy and paste any rows or columns of good HTML that are fairly recent. Now you are ready to revert to a prior version of your HTML, CSS files that will be approx. 2 days older.
https://www.howtogeek.com/209080/how-to-restore-previous-versions-of-a-file-on-any-operating-system/