# Git: restore file with local changes after removal

Tags: linux, git, file-recovery

I doubt git keeps this in memory, but perhaps I missed an option.

I modified a file on my local repository, and then I did `git rm file`. I would like to restore `file` in its previous state, ie. my local modified copy. `git checkout file` will restore it to the latest versionned state, losing my changes...
If there still a way to recover my changes?

Comment: Did you use an IDE like Eclipse or other, which may have an local version history? (http://www.aaronwest.net/blog/index.cfm/2007/3/23/Do-You-Know-About-Eclipses-Local-History and http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm)

Comment: I'm using sublime text, and since I closed the file it seems no history is kept :(

Comment: Did git not warn you with an "Error: the file has local modifications" message?

Comment: @squiroid Suggesting `reset --hard` right away without explaining the impliciations of the command is really, really dangerous. Furthermore you can use `git checkout -- path/to/file` to checkout the latest version of a specific file.

Comment: Sorry for that my bad :-( .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750049/is-it-possible-to-restore-deleted-untracked-files-in-git) there is no option to restore untracked changes except through an external tool. Sorry :/