# How to reverse 'git clean -xdf'

Tags: git, git-clean

I accidentaly run:

```
 git clean -xdf
```

And deleted all the files I needed locally, how can I revert it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restore files deleted with git clean -df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40621770/restore-files-deleted-with-git-clean-df)