# Git - Get untracked files with checkout commit id

Tags: git, git-checkout

Remote repo has a commit that it has some untracked files. I need these files. The current master branch don't have these files.

I used below command to return a specific commit :

```
git checkout commitID
```

It gets untracked files. But I delete these files by using command+delete. After this action, checkout doesn't get untracked files. How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean with a commit thas has untracked files, there is no such thing. Please explain.

Comment: Some files added to repo with older commit(commitFirst). Their names added in gitignore file. Then, these file removed from the repo. Current master branch doesn't have these files. But I need them. To get these files, I use `git checkout commitFirst`. But they are not on my local.

Comment: If they were tracked earlier, then yes, checking out a commit from back when they were tracked should place them in your working folder.

Comment: I am not sure they were tracked. Because I look commit history from bitbucket, they are not seen in diff files.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Before I delete these file from my local with coomand+delete, I could recover them using `git checkout commitid`. But now, I cannot it.

Comment: Were they ever committed, or just added to .gitignore?

Comment: Ohh, sorry. This is my fault. Wrong commit id! `git checkout` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete your untracked files once , git can't bring back those files .

I suggest you to look at this question :   Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750049/is-it-still-possible-to-restore-deleted-untracked-files-in-git)

Comment: Why? This is only local actions. Remote repo has a history. And I think, these files exists on history stack.